# Constructing a stochastic process indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider $\{S_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ to be the simple symmetric random walk with $S_0=0$ and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i$ are iid and $P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=-1)=1/2$. Is it possible to construct a process $\{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$
$$\{Y_n\}_{n\ge k}=\{S_n\}_{n\ge 1}$$

This was suggested to me by a teacher. I assume the equality of stochastic processes imply that all finite dimensional distributions are same. But I seem to have a discrepancy, though my teacher insists that's not possible. I'd appreciate if someone pointed out the mistake in my logic and pointed me towards the right direction.

So, assuming such a $\{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ exists, we can take $k=1$ and then $Y_1$ and $S_1$ must have the same distribution. Hence $P(Y_1=\pm 1)=1$. But let's take $k=-2$ say. Then $Y_1$ and $S_4$ has the same distribution. But then $P(Y_1=4)=1/16>0$ contradicting $Y_1=\pm 1 \text{ ae}$. So no such stochastic process exists.

Comment: Your proof of nonexistence is fine (already $k=1$ and $k=0$ works).

Comment: At first it seems you are just defining a "shifted" random walk, or a random walk with a random variable initial condition.  On the other hand if you mean to have $Y_k=S_1$ and $Y_{k+1} = S_2$ for all integers $k$ it would require $S_1=S_2$ which is not necessarily the case. That property is weird and my guess is that it is a mis-interpretation of some other problem. Perhaps your teacher is just defining a shifted random walk and you mis-interpreted.

Comment: It is impossible to find a $Y_n$ which satisfies $Y_{n+k}=S_n$ for all $k$ and for all $n$. However, for all $k$, it is possible to find $Y_n$ so $Y_{n+k}=S_n$ for all $n$. Perhaps your teacher meant the second interpretation?